# How do I specify a range in android mpchart?

Tags: android

I'm trying to display x-axis data using barchart.
However, there is a lot of X-axis data at 10,000.
As a result, the bar of data on a specific x-axis appears very thin.
So I want to group the bars in units of 500.
How can I make bars in batches of 500?
thank you